# Rational points of projective spaces over rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\mathbf{P}^n_A = \text{Proj} A[T_0,\ldots,T_n]$. If $A$ is a field, there is a simple classical description of $X(A)$. However, if $A$ is a more general ring, like $\mathbf{Z}$, I don't see an easy way to characterize rational points.

For example, we could try to characterize it as graded morphisms
\begin{align*}
A[T_0,\ldots,T_n] \to A[T]
\end{align*}
but it seems that two different morphisms can correspond to the same rational point.

What is the best way to see the set $X(A)$?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46116/a-valued-points-of-projective-space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Intuitively*, morphisms from some space $X$ into projective $n$-space are determined by line bundles ${\mathcal L}$ on $X$ equipped with $n+1$ global sections $s_0,...,s_n$ of ${\mathcal L}$ that are nowhere simultaneously vanishing. The idea is that, at any fixed $x\in X$, you can pick one $s_i$ with $s_i(x)\neq 0$, which then trivializes the fiber of ${\mathcal L}$ at $x$ and reduces all other sections $s_j(x)$ for $j\neq i$, to scalars $s_j(x)/s_i(x)$. You can then send $x$ to the point $\left[\frac{s_0(x)}{s_i(x)}:...:\frac{s_n(x)}{s_i(x)}\right]$ in ${\mathbb P}^n$, which is independent on the choice of $i$ such that $s_i(x)\neq 0$, since choosing instead any other $i^{\prime}$ with $s_{i^{\prime}}(x)\neq 0$ only results in a scaling of the homogeneous coordinates by $\frac{s_i(x)}{s_{i^{\prime}}(x)}$. Conversely, given any morphism $X\to {\mathbb P}^n$ induces a line bundle with $n+1$ nowhere simultaneously vanishing sections on $X$ by pulling back ${\mathcal O}(1)$ with its standard sections from ${\mathbb P}^n$.

*Formally*, for a scheme $X$ the $X$-rational points of ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb Z}^n$ are in bijection with equivalence classes of pairs $({\mathcal L},(s_0,...,s_n))$ where ${\mathcal L}$ is rank $1$ locally free coherent sheaf on $X$ and $s_i\in {\mathcal L}(X)$ are global sections such that ${\mathcal L}_x = {\mathcal O}_{X,x}\cdot\{(s_i)_x\}$, i.e. for any $x\in X$ there is some $i$ with $(s_i)_x\notin{\mathfrak m}_{x}{\mathcal L}_x$. Note that given ${\mathcal L}$, the tuple $(s_0,...,s_n)$ with the above requirement is the same as a surjective morphism ${\mathcal O}_X^{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow{\mathcal L}$, and you identify two such morphisms ${\mathcal O}_X^{n+1}\to {\mathcal L}$ and ${\mathcal O}_X^{n+1}\to {\mathcal L}^{\prime}$ if they differ by an isomorphism between ${\mathcal L}$ and ${\mathcal L}^{\prime}$.

See *Goertz-Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry I, 8.5: Projective space as a Grassmannian*

If $X=\text{Spec}(A)$, over which vector bundles correspond to projective $A$-modules, this means that $\text{Spec}(A)$-valued points of ${\mathbb P}_{\mathbb Z}^n$, i.e. $A$-rational points of ${\mathbb P}_A^n$, are in bijection with equivalence classes of rank $1$ projective $A$-modules $P$ equipped with $n+1$ elements $s_0,...,s_n\in P$ generating $P$. For example, if $P=A$, then the $s_i$ are ring elements that are to satisfy $(s_i)=A$, and you identify two such tuples $(s_i)$ and $(s^{\prime}_j)$ if they differ by a unit in $A$. In case $A$ is a field (over which any module is free), this gives you the familiar description of ${\mathbb P}_k^n(k)$ as $(k^{n+1}\setminus \{0\})/k^{\times}$, but you could also take $A={\mathbb Z}$ (over which any projective module is free) and see that ${\mathbb Z}$-points of ${\mathbb P}^n_{\mathbb Z}$ are in bijection with $(n+1)$-tuples $(s_0,...,s_n)\in{\mathbb Z}^{n+1}$ of coprime integers, up to overall multiplication by $\pm 1$.

Comment: Ok, I know that you can describe morphisms to projective space as equivalence classes of line bundles with $n+1$ generating global sections. The reason that I was searching for an alternate description is that I can't understand very well the relation between $\mathbf{P}^n(A)$ and $\mathbf{P}^n(K)$ if $K$ is the fraction field of $A$. But actually I see now why, at least for a Dedeking ring, these two sets should be the same.

Comment: @Jacques: Mh no they are not the same. For example, any $(a,b)\in {\mathbb Z}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ defines a ${\mathbb Q}$-valued point in ${\mathbb P}^1_{\mathbb Z}$, but it defines a ${\mathbb Z}$-valued point only if $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: @Hanno: Your statement is wrong; the $A$ and $K$-valued points of a projective scheme (or more generally a proper scheme) over a DVR $A$ are the same.  In your attempted counterexample, note that if we write $a = a'd, b = b'd,$ where $d = $gcd$(a,b)$, then the $\mathbb Q$-valued point $[a:b]$ in projective space is equal to the point $[a':b']$, and so is also a $\mathbb Z$-valued point.  You may want to learn about the valuative criterion for properness (which implies this general statement) and look at the proof (given in Hartshorne) that projective varieties are proper, which proceeds ...

Comment: ... via the valuative criterion, and uses the technique of dividing through by the g.c.d. which I used above.

Comment: Hanno, it seems to me that $\{(a,b) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \setminus\{0\} \mid \text{gcd}(a,b)=1\}/\mathbf{Z}^{\times}$ is bijective to  $(\mathbf{Q}^2\setminus\{0\})/\mathbf{Q}^{\times}$.

Tracing, I don't know if we can apply the valuative criterion in this case (since $\mathbf{Z}$ is not a DVR).

Comment: Dear Jacques & tracing: You're right, I'm sorry. @Jacques: How did you check the bijection ${\mathbb P}^n(A)\to{\mathbb P}^n(K)$ (for $A$ a Dedekind ring with quotient field $K$) when $A$ is not necessarily a PID? Via the explicit description of rank $1$ projective modules as fractional ideals?

Comment: Yes. We know that $\text{Pic}(A)$ and $\text{Cl}(A)$ are canonically isomorphic. Thus, to give $(\mathcal{L},(s_i))$ up to equivalence amounts to give a fractional ideal $I$ of $A$ and a sequence of $n+1$ generating elements $a_i$ of $I$, up to multiplication by an element of $K^{\times}$ which amounts to give $n+1$ elements $a_i$ in $K$ not all zero up to multiplication by an element of $K^{\times}$, i.e. a point in $\mathbf{P}^n(K)$.

Comment: @Jacques Thank you, that was also what I had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The algebraic description of $\mathbb P^n_A(A)$ is of biblical simplicity:

> **It consists  of all submodules $M\subset A^{n+1}$ which are direct summands of rank one.**

As the French poet Verlaine wrote: *Et tout le reste est littérature* ("And all the rest is literature")
Here however is some of that *littérature*:

1) To say that $M$ is a direct summand  means that there exists a submodule $N\subset A$ such that $A^{n+1}=M\oplus N$.

2) To say that $M$ is of rank one means that for each maximal prime $\mathfrak m\subset A$ the automatically free  $A_\mathfrak m$-module $M_\mathfrak m$ has dimension $1$.

3) Among these projective direct summands of rank  are the free ones: they consist **exactly** of modules $M$ which can be written $M=A(a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)\subset A^{n+1}$ with the $a_i$'s satisfying $\sum_{i=0}^n Aa_i=A$.
We might then write for tradition's sake $M=[a_0:a_1:\cdots:a_n]$.
The module $M$ can also be written  $M=A(b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_n)$  if and only if there exists an invertible element $u\in A^\times$ such that $(b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_n)=u(a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in A^{n+1}$.

4) For some rings $A$ all  direct summands of rank one will be free [i.e. of the type described in 3)]: this is the case if $A$ is a PID or if $A$ is a local ring.

5) But this is not true for all rings. Here is an example of a non free direct summand of rank one:
 The ideal $I=\langle 2,1+\sqrt -5\rangle\subset A=\mathbb Z[\sqrt -5]$ is known to be a non-free projective A-module of rank one.
There is a surjective morphism of $A$-modules $p:A^2\to I: (a,b)\mapsto a\cdot2+b\cdot\sqrt -5$.
Since $I$ is projective, $p$ has an $A$-linear  section $s:I\to A^2$ (i.e. $p\circ s:I\to I$ is the identity).
Then the image $M:=s(I)$ is a direct summand of rank one of $A^2=M\oplus ker (p)$, and $M$ is thus an element of $\mathbb P^1_A(A)$ not of the form $A(a,b)$.
In other words $M\in \mathbb P^n_A(A)$ cannot be thought of as some $[a:b]$, in contrast to what happens over a field $k$, where elements of $\mathbb P^1_k(k)$ can always be written $[a:b]$.